# Use dictionary comprehension to read a CSV file? Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to mimic this code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
   k, v = row
   d[k] = v
print(d)
```

Using dictionary comprehension instead of a for loop. All it does it take the key value pairs in the CSV file and put them into a dictionary. Its a simple CSV file with 10 pairs of numbers. It should output like this to match the original:

```
{'1': '3.5', '2': '5.6', '3': '1.7', '4': '-0.1', '5': '27', '6': '33', '7': '13.7', '8': '-4', '9': '10.5', '10': '24.8'}
```

I am still newish to Python so any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: That would be `d = {k:v for k, v in reader}`

Comment: That keeps coming up as a blank dictionary.

Comment: If you are trying it after you have already done the `for` loop, then you have exhausted all the values from the iterator. Reopen the file and try again.

Comment: I did, still coming back as {}. maybe its my Mac? lol. I commented out the for loop, closed Pycharm and the excel doc and opened both back up still comes back blank

Comment: could you please provide the first few rows of filename.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

current_date = datetime.now()

today = (current_date.month, current_date.day)

data = pandas.read_csv("birthdays.csv")

birthday_dict = {(data_row["month"], data_row["day"]): data_row for (index, data_row) in data.iterrows()}
```

Comment: What happens here?  Pandas, birthdays, `today`…

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
birthday_dict = {(data_row["month"], data_row["day"]): data_row for (index, data_row) in data.iterrows()}
```

To make sure this line is easier to understand:

- {(data_row["month"], data_row["day"]): data_row for (index, data_row) in data.iterrows()}: This is a dictionary comprehension. For each row in the DataFrame, it creates a key-value pair in the dictionary. The key is a tuple containing the "month" and "day" values from the current row, and the value is the entire row (the Series).
- data.iterrows() is used here to make sure we can iterate each row of the data file (csv)

Another good example how it works can be found below:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Assuming you've read the CSV file into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv("birthdays.csv")

current_date = datetime.now()

# Extract the month and day from the current date
today = (current_date.month, current_date.day)

# Create a dictionary where keys are (month, day) tuples and values are the corresponding rows
birthday_dict = {(data_row["month"], data_row["day"]): data_row for (index, data_row) in data.iterrows()}

# Display the resulting dictionary
print(birthday_dict)
```

And this is the result:

```
{
    (5, 12): {'name': 'Alice', 'month': 5, 'day': 12},
    (3, 8): {'name': 'Bob', 'month': 3, 'day': 8},
    (9, 21): {'name': 'Charlie', 'month': 9, 'day': 21}
}
```

How it makes it a little bit more clear.